# Do I need to have a parameter for d3.js selectAll() function for a data join?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

```
const root = d3.select("#root");
root.selectAll("circle") // This line
     .data(fruits)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => i * 120 + 60)
    .attr("cy", svgHeight / 2)
    .attr('fill', '#c11d1d')
    .attr('r', 50);
```

Do I need a to enter "circle" in the `root.selectAll("circle")` function if I have no DOM elements named circle? I am not sure why the parameter is necessary since I am later appending "circle". I tried this with `.selectAll("rect")` (instead of circle) and then appending circles to it and also not passing a parameter and appending circles and my result was the same. It seems that it is not necessary to pass a parameter if there are no DOM elements but the tutorial I am looking at does it.

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate because I think the explanation in the dupe target is sufficient to answer your problem, right? If your question is not anwered by that particular post  I'd be happy to reopen your post, though.